# Can't get simple Apache VHost up and running

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get a simple Apache VHost online. I used to simply have one VHost which bound to all: `<VirtualHost *:80>`, but this isn't appropriate for security anymore. I need to have one VHost for localhost requests (ie my dev server) and one for incoming requests via my domain name.

Here's my new VHost:

```
NameVirtualHost domain1.com

<VirtualHost domain1.com:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ServerName domain1.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost domain2.com:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ServerName domain2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

After I restart my server, I see the following errors in my log:

```
[Wed Feb 16 11:26:36 2011] [error] [client ####.###.###.###] File does not exist: /htdocs
[Wed Feb 16 11:26:36 2011] [error] [client ####.###.###.###] File does not exist: /htdocs
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

## EDIT

As per the answer give below, I have modified my configuration. Here are my configuration files:

**/etc/apache2/ports.conf**:

```
Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Here are my actual defined sites:

**/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-localhost**:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerAdmin #########

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/mod_rewrite.log"
    RewriteLogLevel 9

    <Location />
            <Limit GET POST PUT>
                    order allow,deny
                    allow from all
                    deny from 65.34.248.110
                    deny from 69.122.239.3
                    deny from 58.218.199.147
                    deny from 65.34.248.110
            </Limit>
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-rfkrocktk.dyndns.org**:

```
NameVirtualHost rfkrocktk.dyndns.org:80

<VirtualHost rfkrocktk.dyndns.org:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ServerName rfkrocktk.dyndns.org
</VirtualHost>
```

And, just for kicks, my main file:

**/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**:

```
#
# Based upon the NCSA server configuration files originally by Rob McCool.
#
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ for detailed information about
# the directives.
#
# Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
# what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
# consult the online docs. You have been warned.  
#
# The configuration directives are grouped into three basic sections:
#  1. Directives that control the operation of the Apache server process as a
#     whole (the 'global environment').
#  2. Directives that define the parameters of the 'main' or 'default' server,
#     which responds to requests that aren't handled by a virtual host.
#     These directives also provide default values for the settings
#     of all virtual hosts.
#  3. Settings for virtual hosts, which allow Web requests to be sent to
#     different IP addresses or hostnames and have them handled by the
#     same Apache server process.
#
# Configuration and logfile names: If the filenames you specify for many
# of the server's control files begin with "/" (or "drive:/" for Win32), the
# server will use that explicit path.  If the filenames do *not* begin
# with "/", the value of ServerRoot is prepended -- so "/var/log/apache2/foo.log"
# with ServerRoot set to "" will be interpreted by the
# server as "//var/log/apache2/foo.log".
#

### Section 1: Global Environment
#
# The directives in this section affect the overall operation of Apache,
# such as the number of concurrent requests it can handle or where it
# can find its configuration files.
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the LockFile documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs-2.1/mod/mpm_common.html#lockfile>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
#<IfModule !mpm_winnt.c>
#<IfModule !mpm_netware.c>
LockFile /var/lock/apache2/accept.lock
#</IfModule>
#</IfModule>

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 15

##
## Server-Pool Size Regulation (MPM specific)
## 

# prefork MPM
# StartServers: number of server processes to start
# MinSpareServers: minimum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxSpareServers: maximum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxClients: maximum number of server processes allowed to start
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# worker MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MaxClients: maximum number of simultaneous client connections
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# event MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MaxClients: maximum number of simultaneous client connections
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers          2
    MaxClients          150
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#

AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
# viewed by Web clients. 
#
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Files>

#
# DefaultType is the default MIME type the server will use for a document
# if it cannot otherwise determine one, such as from filename extensions.
# If your server contains mostly text or HTML documents, "text/plain" is
# a good value.  If most of your content is binary, such as applications
# or images, you may want to use "application/octet-stream" instead to
# keep browsers from trying to display binary files as though they are
# text.
#
DefaultType text/plain


#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
Include /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/*.load
Include /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include all the user configurations:
Include /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

# Include ports listing
Include /etc/apache2/ports.conf

#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive (see below).
# If you are behind a reverse proxy, you might want to change %h into %{X-Forwarded-For}i
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

#
# Define an access log for VirtualHosts that don't define their own logfile
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log vhost_combined


# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
Include /etc/apache2/conf.d/

# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
```

what else do I need to do to fix it? Should I be telling apache to listen on 127.0.0.1:80, or isn't it already listening there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated above you should alter your configuration a bit to use the directive `NameVirtualHost` correctly.

Also, for the name based virtual hosts to work you will need to define a ServerName in the default configuration.

Edit the files to match this:

**/etc/apache2/ports.conf**

```
Listen 80  
NameVirtualHost THE_PUBLIC_OR_LAN_IP_OF_THE_SERVER:80
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
    Listen 443 </IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443  </IfModule>
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-rfkrocktk.dyndns.org:**

```
<VirtualHost THE_PUBLIC_OR_LAN_IP_OF_THE_SERVER:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ServerName rfkrocktk.dyndns.org  
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What if I don't have the IP address of the server? As I'm running DynDNS, I don't have the actual server IP address, as it's dynamically assigned to my by my ISP and mapped to DNS by the DynDNS service.

Comment: If your server is placed behind a LAN and you forward a port to the server, then you should use the LAN IP address. However, if that is not the case you could use a wildcard, so instead of an IP you could replace my "THE_PUBLIC..." with a * thus making it `NameVirtualHost *:80` and `<VirtualHost *:80>`

Comment: Sweet, that worked. I basically specified my catchall `NameVirtualHost *:80` first in the ports file, and that seems to work great. Is there any other way to filter virtual hosts? I'd really like to be able to do it by requested domain name.

Comment: You do that with the "ServerName" directive in each virtual host. You can in the ports.conf set a generic one, so any other vhost will not default to the first one. Do that by entering `ServerName myserver.domain.com` in the ports.conf.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to check how the listener is configured (the `Listen` configuration directive).
`NameVirtualHost` should be followed by an entry like: `ip:port` or `*:port`.
In your case:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
Listen 192.168.10.30:80

NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80
NameVirtualHost 192.168.10.30:80 # Your "external" IP.

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.10.30:80>   # Same signature as NameVirtualHost
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Indeed, the individual `VirtualHost` directives in this case don't match the  `NameVirtualHost` directive as they specify a port while the `NameVirtualHost` doesn't.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your answer, but unfortunately I'm still having problems. I have edited the question above to include more details/server configuration files to help debug what's going wrong. Thanks again :)